# Why do confidence intervals width increase when sample size increases "a bit"?

Tags: confidence-interval, random-variable, simulation, sample-size

I'll try to explain better. I sampled a LogNormal random variate and I extracted 12001 and 12002 samples (with same initial seed for Random Number Generator). In the first case the half width of confidence interval (for mean) is 0.36633536625893326, while in the second case the width is 0.36636953704150527. Comparing two numbers `0.36633536625893326 >= 0.36636953704150527` is **false**.

So I don't understand why width is increased. I know that when sample size **increases** confidence intervals **decrease**. Maybe did I make some mistakes? Or is this a normal behavior?

Comment: I assume you are looking at the CI for the mean, right? In any case, the CI width can certainly increase if the new data point is far away from the initial estimate of the mean, because this would of course reduce our confidence in the updated estimate.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 6):

A standard confidence interval for a mean is calculated using $s/\sqrt n$. If you increase $n$ but also increase the sample standard deviation $s$ by enough to offset the larger sample size, then your $s/\sqrt n$ increases, widening your confidence interval.

$$\text{Standard Confidence Interval for a Mean}\\
\bigg(
\bar x - t_{critical}\dfrac{s}{\sqrt n},
\bar x + t_{critical}\dfrac{s}
{\sqrt n}
\bigg)
$$